# Program type already present: android.support.v4.R

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to generate a signed apk and I am getting the error:

> Program type already present: android.support.v4.R

I have tried excluding `support-v4` from some dependencies. But that didn't help. I have searched for answers but none couldn't solve mine. 
But the app runs in debug mode fine.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Here's my gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.android.puchotask1"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }


    }


    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
        implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7'
        implementation 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.dnkilic.waveform:waveform:0.9.3'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle project file

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the support appcompat-v7 from this [dependency](https://github.com/dnkilic/android-siri-wave/blob/master/waveform/build.gradle):

```
implementation 'com.dnkilic.waveform:waveform:0.9.3'
```

with this:

```
implementation ('com.dnkilic.waveform:waveform:0.9.3') {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support'
     exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```